# E-Mail headers with IP address as a receiver, but not as a sender

Tags: networking, email, ip

When I sent an email with my client the receiver can see my IP address in the header. This is okay and fine with me.Then I tried to check the header in my "sent" folder and took a look to the header but there is no ip:

Beside the body this is the only information I have in the header:

```
From: ****  <***>
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Mime-Version: 1.0 (*****)
Subject: ****
X-Universally-Unique-Identifier: ****-****-****-*****
Message-Id: <*****@****>
To: ****  <***>
```

Is here any way to get the senders ip address with this information? I am wondering at what point the ip is added and why its not accessible in my sent folder?

Comment: It will get added by the first email server in the chain of servers between and the recipient.

Comment: The IP isn't known until it's sent. It's added as it arrives at the first node.

Comment: Ah okay - I see. So its not possible (even with login) to get the added ip information from a email I have sent? What is in my mind is to do a "request" to the "first node" with my email login information to receive the information which were added to the header.

Comment: What's your ultimate goal here? To know your external IP address, or to remember where you were when you sent an email?

Comment: The goal is to get an information about an email which was sent and is in my sent folder - which I did not sent. I already asked the receiver for the header information but he is not able to give me this information. This is why I tried to figure out at what point an ip is set. I also asked my email provider to give me information but because of privacy policy they do not give me log data.

Comment: The information isn't added until the mail reaches the first node, so there's no way to discover it from your sent mailbox.

Comment: Alright. Then I have to continue to explain the receiver how to send me the header information and hope, to find out who sent the mail. Thanks for the information! :)